# Flask Saving a selected value from a field and displaying it on another page

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm new to Flask and am facing difficulties saving the value that is selected from an option of four different coffee roasts and displaying it on another page. One one page (Roast.html) the user has the option to select one coffee roast from Light, Medium, Dark, and Special. After the submit button is pressed, I want to show this selection on the next page (Brew.html) i.e. "Your _____ roast coffee is now brewing!" Any help would be greatly appreciated! I would prefer not to involve php or javascript in this code. Thank you

coffeeMaker.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import url_for
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def welcome():
    return render_template("welcome.html")

@app.route('/Roast', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def roast():
    print "inside Roast"
    return render_template("Roast.html")

@app.route('/Brew', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def brew():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print 456
        a = request.query_string
        print 789
        return render_template("Brew.html",selection = a )   
    else:
        return "This is a GET request."



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

welcome.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to Coffee Maker</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is a website for you to order your coffee of perference
</h1>
<a href = "/Roast" >ready for a coffee</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Roast.html:

```
<html>
<form action="/Brew" method="Post">    
  <h3>2. Choose your Roast</h3>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="roastType" value="Light">Light
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="roastType" value="Medium" checked>Medium
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="roastType" value="Dark">Dark
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="roastType" value="HackGT Blend">Special Blend
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Brew It">
</form>
</html>
```

Brew.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
brew
</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Brewing</h1>
<p>You selected{{selection}}</p>
<p>Get ready for your perfect cup of coffee~</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to grab the element from the `request.form` object:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    brew_type = request.form["roastType"]
    print(brew_type)
    return render_template("Brew.html", selection=brew_type)
```

It's all covered in the [quickstart guide](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#the-request-object).